# How to highlight texts without changing the column margin, IEEE format?

Tags: formatting, color, margins, highlighting, soul

I am trying to present my reviewer response with highlighted texts. I am using the soul package in IEEE double-column format. The issue is, the texts go beyond the column margin. Is there anyone who had the same experience and got it solved?

```
\documentclass{ieeeaccess}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{mathptmx} 
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{color,soul}
\sethlcolor{yellow}
% \renewcommand\hl[1]{#1}

\begin{document}
    
    \hl{We select three linear paths $(\eta_{h}=5.5477~m$, $\eta_{k}=2.234~m$, $\eta_{c}=1.1~m)$ and 
    five angular paths $(\Omega_k \in \{0,\frac{\pi}{6},\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{\pi}{3},\frac{\pi} 
    {2},\frac{2\pi}{3},\frac{3\pi}{4},\frac{5\pi}{6},\pi\}~rad)$ inside the applicable range of the machine. This is a dummy text I am using to show the double margin.I guess you understand it.}
\EOD
\end{document}
```

Then the output will look like the following. I want to maintain the original double-column margin as noted by the arrow. When the highlighting is not applied, the texts fall inside the margin with no issue.
[image]

It works fine with the Article class (see below image)
[image]

Comment: The problem is not the highlighting but the maths environment and the content of that...

Comment: Can you also show this with standard classes like the `article` class? In my tests everything works fine...

Comment: Thanks. The article class works fine. I added an image. See my original post.

Comment: When the highlighting is not applied, the texts fall inside the margin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the mathematical term and the length of the content in the brackets. You need to manually break it:

```
\documentclass{ieeeaccess}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{mathptmx} 
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{color,soul}
\sethlcolor{yellow}

\begin{document}
    
    \hl{We select three linear paths $(\eta_{h}=5.5477~m$, $\eta_{k}=2.234~m$, $\eta_{c}=1.1~m)$ and 
        five angular paths $(\Omega_k \in \{0,\frac{\pi}{6}, \frac{\pi}{4},\frac{\pi}{3},\frac{\pi} 
        {2},\frac{2\pi}{3},$ \\ $\frac{3\pi}{4},\frac{5\pi}{6},\pi\}~rad)$ inside the applicable range of the machine. This is a dummy text I am using to show the double margin.I guess you understand it.}
    \EOD
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or you just write longer / shorter text so the mathematical text does not need to be placed in different lines:

```
\documentclass{ieeeaccess}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{mathptmx} 
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{color,soul}
\sethlcolor{yellow}

\begin{document}
    
    \hl{We select three linear paths $(\eta_{h}=5.5477~m$, $\eta_{k}=2.234~m$, $\eta_{c}=1.1~m)$ and 
        of course we also selected five angular paths $(\Omega_k \in \{0,\frac{\pi}{6}, \frac{\pi}{4},\frac{\pi}{3},\frac{\pi} 
        {2},\frac{2\pi}{3}, \frac{3\pi}{4},\frac{5\pi}{6},\pi\}~rad)$ inside the applicable range of the machine. This is a dummy text I am using to show the double margin.I guess you understand it.}
    \EOD
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes. Thank you very much. Both methods work.

Comment: You don't need the extra slash-space at the break in the math; just a single space should work.  With the slash-space, the broken line is followed by an indentation on the next line.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: a single space does not work. That’s why I’ve added the `\`. Since that is not the best choice and also annoying and not visually the best to manually split the formula, I had added the second version.

Comment: Interesting.  I wouldn't have predicted that.  Thanks.  I'll have to think about this, since the leading space is distracting.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: It is distracting. However, having thought about this some more I concluded that since you know anyways that a new line should be started you can replace `\`with `\\` and therefore remove the distracting space at the beginning of the line. I have updated my answer accordingly. But I still prefer the second version...